# Convert String to JSON node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rpgle

Very new to node.js, I have string returning from RPGLE (as400) program, I would like to return as JSON example below.

String

```
{orderid:996553,workorder:996553.010,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},
{orderid:996554,workorder:996554.010,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.010,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.020,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.030,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.040,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.050,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},
```

Would like to convert as below and send to application api

```
[{"orderid":144234,"workorder":"996553.010","shipped":1,"received":1,"status":"GOOD"},
{"orderid":999290,"workorder":"996553.010","shipped":1,"received":1,"status":"GOOD"},
{"orderid":999290,"workorder":"999290.010","shipped":1,"received":1,"status":"GOOD"},
{"orderid":999290,"workorder":"999290.020","shipped":1,"received":1,"status":"BAD"},
{"orderid":999290,"workorder":"999290.030","shipped":1,"received":1,"status":"GOOD"},
{"orderid":999290,"workorder":"999290.040","shipped":1,"received":1,"status":"GOOD"},
{"orderid":999290,"workorder":"999290.050","shipped":1,"received":1,"status":"GOOD"}]
```

What would be the best practice and how?

Comment: So you have a string and you would like to convert it to a string? I think this is not a problem with JSON right here. Just add "[]" and you're done.

Comment: @NikxDa I agree with the thought, but it's a bit more than just adding `[]` and calling it done.  The keys and values need to be wrapped in quotes as well for it to be parsed correctly in the end.

Comment: True, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Looks like you need an as400 (whatever data structure that's outputting to) to JSON convertor, which will involve lexing/parsing. This probably doesn't exist, and depending on how complex your input string is, you may need to write it yourself. This is probably too broad to answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: Calling it probably would work but isn't best practice - it would be OK if you're 100% sure that he data will always be safe and will always be safe in that case by all means slap some ['s on it (define vars for values of status) and then execute it - just be sure you're aware of the security implications as you'd be executing your data as code (research caveats of using `eval` before doing this). A simple parser probably is a safer option. At least some parsing would be required regardless as your floats remain strings but integers are parsed to numbers by the looks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this string conversion through a series of regular expressions and a little decision logic to determine string and numeric values.

```js
var meh = "{orderid:996553,workorder:996553.010,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},\
{orderid:996554,workorder:996554.010,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},\
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.010,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},\
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.020,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},\
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.030,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},\
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.040,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},\
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.050,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},";

meh = "[" +                                         // enclose with []
  meh.replace(/(\w+)(?=:)/g, '"$1"')                // search for words followed by a colon
    .replace(/,$/, '')                              // trim the ending comma
    .replace(/:([\w.]+)/g, function(match, value){  // grab the values
      return ':' + (                                // ensure preceding colon is in place
        isNaN(value) || value % 1 !== 0 ?           // is it a non-float number?
          '"' + value + '"' :                       // enclose with "" if not a non-float number
          parseFloat(value)                         // parse if is number
      );
    })
  + "]";                                            // enclose with []

console.log(JSON.parse(meh));
```

Comment: that did the trick thank you, can you explain this line in details please `meh.replace(/(\w+)(?=:)/g, '"$1"')` . Working great

Comment: When string return from RPGLE got À at beginning of the string so just needed to substring as didn't find anything on RPGLE program OUTPUT but when display string though node.js got  À . very strange

Comment: @Nick `.replace(/(\w+)(?=:)/g, '"$1"')`. First, the regular expression `/(\w+)(?=:)/g`.  `\w` stands for a "word character". Technically it's the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so any of those characters for 1 or more characters (represented by the `+`. It's like `*`, but instead of 0 or more, it's 1 or more).  That is captured into a capturing group using `(...)`. The `(?=:)` is a lookahead represented by `(?=...)`.  It "looks ahead" for a single colon character.  The pattern matches any word followed by a colon. Lastly It replaces our captured group with itself wrapped in quotes (``"$1"``).

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure what the `À` issue is.  I'm not familiar with RPGLE.  Is that like the old Report Program Generator?

Comment: thanks for make it clear. Yes, it is old IBM AS400 ,Report Program Generator

Comment: What do you mean by `old IBM AS400 RPG`? That is like saying old Java or even older C. Are you using a computer built between 1988 and 1999? That is when the `old AS/400s` were made. They didn't even support RPGLE until the last iteration. Or are you using something a bit newer?

Comment: How long is the string you are parsing? You didn't show the RPGLE, but variable length strings are prepended with a length, and you could inadvertently be overlaying a `VARCHAR` with a `CHAR`. In that case the first characters may be strange.

Answer (score 2):

You could parse the lines into valid javascript objects and then stringify them into JSON like this:

```js
const s = `
{orderid:996553,workorder:996553.010,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},
{orderid:996554,workorder:996554.010,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.010,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.020,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.030,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.040,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},
{orderid:999290,workorder:999290.050,shipped:000000001,received:000000001,status:GOOD},
`;

const array = s.trim().split("\n").map((line) => 
  line
    .slice(1, -2) // remove brackets and comma
    .split(",") // break into individual key/value pairs
    .map((pair) => pair.split(":")) // split key/value pairs
    .reduce((result, [key, value]) => { // reduce pairs into an object
      result[key] = value;
      return result;
    },{})
);

const json = JSON.stringify(array, null, 2);

console.log(json);
```

Comment: thanks for your help but accepted answer work for us. Tried your suggestion but it was returning API as `text/plain` and application which reads the API, didn't like that . Tried to return as json but didn't like `"` for all values.

Answer (score 1):

How is the RPGLE program creating the string? If it is doing it piece by piece, then the RPGLE program could probably add the quotes and format the numbers correctly.